# Before-Save Flows

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, before-trigger

Apparently there are now before-save flows in which it is possible to update records before the save :

[Before-Save Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_concepts_trigger_record.htm&type=0)

I have not had the chance to use them yet. Does anybody know how to invoke a before-save autolaunch flow ? It doesn't seem like it would be possible to do it through Process Builder because I don't think Process Builder can be launched until after a change has been made to a record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special. Create a new flow, double-click the Start element to choose the trigger behavior, build the rest of the flow, save it, then activate it. It'll automatically start doing its thing the very next time a record meets the criteria (you can choose insert, update, or insert and update).

[image: Set Start Conditions]

---

[image: Build Flow]

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks sfdcfox !

Comment: One other question : Is it possible to put a criteria on the update ? Like a specific is changed ?

Comment: @Zoom_v You can use Decision elements to decide what you want to do, just like other flows.

Comment: Can I determine if a field has changed in a Decision element ? I don't think it has the equivalent of an IsChanged, does it ?

Comment: @Zoom_v I thought there was one, but no, you can't say if a field "has changed", only if a field meets a certain value (or not). This tech doesn't replace the need for triggers, but it can reduce that need, and does fit a large number of useful situations.

Comment: Oh well. It's still an awesome addition to Flow. I'll find plenty of uses for it for sure. Thanks again !

Comment: discovered today that if you add a get records element and get a copy of the current record (ie filter where id = $record.id) then you have access to the current values and can compute if changed, etc.  now that might blow up on insert...still testing that.

Comment: amazing, works fine on insert - i guess there are no matches when $record.id = null but still nice for something in flow to handle things gracefully instead of going up in flames.